# Test if Haskell variable matches user-defined data type option

Tags: haskell, types, typechecking

So I have a data type sort of like:

```
data Token = NUM Int | ID String | EOF
```

and I have a function sort of like:

```
doStuff list = let
       (token, rest) = getToken list
   in
       ....
```

So what I want to do in the `...` part is test if the token I got is a `NUM` or `INT` or `EOF`. I can say `token==EOF` to test for that case, but I can't figure out a way to test if the token is a `NUM` or `INT` using a conditional, since `token==(NUM n)` and `token==NUM` both result in errors. I know that I could write a helper function to do the stuff in the `...` and take advantage of pattern matching, but that really hurts  the readability of what I'm doing, and it seems like there should be a way to do this check. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want a `case` expression, like:

```hs
case token of
    NUM n -> foo n
    ID s  -> bar s
    _     -> hoho
```

That's the same sort of pattern matching as you'd get if you defined a function separately.

Answer (score 8):

One cute trick for this is to use record syntax. The advantage of this approach is that it keeps working even if the number of arguments to a particular constructor changes. Note that the data type itself need not be declared using record syntax to take advantage of this trick.

```
case token of
    NUM {} -> ...
    ID  {} -> ...
    EOF {} -> ...
```

Comment: @mergeconflict If you want the values, you don't use this trick, of course. =) But it sounded from the question like he only wanted to check which constructor was used.

Comment: @mergeconflict you can selectively get the vals like this: `data Token = NUM { n,m :: Int}` --- `case tokenVal of Num {n=n'} -> foo n'`