# How to tell whether variable is a certain data in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Edit: This class instance of `QWhere` fails when it's passed input like this: `>qWhere fly john` even though `fly` is type `Argument -> Argument -> Predicate` and `john` is type `Argument`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Argument = Argument { ttype :: Type, value :: String } deriving (Show, Eq)
data Predicate = Predicate { lemma :: String, arguments :: [Argument] } deriving (Show, Eq)

class Fly a b where
      fly :: a -> b -> Predicate

instance Fly Argument Argument where
      fly x y = Predicate { lemma = "fly", arguments = [x, y] }

instance Fly Argument Predicate where
      fly x y = Predicate { lemma = "fly", arguments = [x, arguments y !! 0] }

class QWhere a b where
            qWhere :: a -> b -> String

instance QWhere (Argument -> Argument -> Predicate) Argument where
            qWhere x y = "hi"
```

This is the output from the ghci:

```
No instance for (QWhere (a0 -> b0 -> Predicate) Argument)
  arising from a use of ‘qWhere’
The type variables ‘a0’, ‘b0’ are ambiguous
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance QWhere (Argument -> Argument -> Predicate) Argument
    -- Defined at new_context.hs:116:10
In the expression: qWhere fly john
In an equation for ‘it’: it = qWhere fly john

No instance for (Fly a0 b0) arising from a use of ‘fly’
The type variables ‘a0’, ‘b0’ are ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Fly Argument Predicate
    -- Defined at new_context.hs:110:10
  instance Fly Argument Argument
    -- Defined at new_context.hs:107:10
In the first argument of ‘qWhere’, namely ‘fly’
In the expression: qWhere fly john
In an equation for ‘it’: it = qWhere fly john
```

These questions are relevant, but none of the answers have solved my problem.

(1) [Checking for a particular data constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088935/checking-for-a-particular-data-constructor)

(2) [Test if Haskell variable matches user-defined data type option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897559/test-if-haskell-variable-matches-user-defined-data-type-option)

And some internet sources which should address this question but I could not find the solution from:

(3) https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Determining_the_type_of_an_expression

(4) http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/typeEQ.html

My problem: I have two Haskell **data** types defined.  I am given an input and I need to determine if it belongs to data type A or data type B.

Here is the data types definition:

```
data Argument = Argument { ttype :: Type, value :: String } deriving (Show, Eq)
data Predicate = Predicate { lemma :: String, arguments :: [Argument] } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I need a function which returns true/false if a variable is a data type Argument or Predicate.

I attempted to follow the answers of both SO questions, but only got complaints from the ghci compiler:

```
--checks if a variable is of data type Argument
--this does not compile (from question (2))
isArgument :: a -> Bool
isArgument (Argument _) = True
isArgument _ = False

--from question (1), also fails
isArgument :: a -> String
isArgument value = 
    case token of
        Argument arg -> "is argument"
        Predicate p -> "is predicate"
```

Answer (score 2):

The sort of dynamic typing you are trying to do is very rarely used in Haskell. If you want to write functions that can take values of both `Predicate` and `Argument` there are at least two idiomatic ways depending on your exact use-case.

The first is to overload the function using type-classes. E.g.

```
class IsArgument a where
    isArgument :: a -> Bool

instance IsArgument Argument where
    isArgument _ = True

instance IsArgument Predicate where
    isArgument _ = False
```

The second is to use some sum-type such as `Either Predicate Argument` or a custom sum-type such as:

```
data Expr = ArgumentExpr Argument | PredicateExpr Predicate

isArgument :: Expr -> Bool
isArgument (ArgumentExpr _) = True
isArgument _                = False
```

You can also make `Argument` and `Predicate` constructors of the same type, but then of course you lose the type safety of treating them as separate types. You can circumvent this by using a GADT and tagging the constructors with a phantom type but this gets into the slightly more advanced type extensions that GHC offers:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

data ExprType = Argument | Predicate

data Expr t where
    ArgumentExpr  :: { ttype :: Type, value :: String } -> Expr Argument
    PredicateExpr :: { lemma :: String, arguments :: [Expr Argument] } -> Expr Predicate

deriving instance Show (Expr t)
deriving instance Eq (Expr t)

isArgument :: Expr t -> Bool
isArgument (ArgumentExpr {}) = True
isArgument _ = False
```

Now arguments and predicates are constructors of the same type but you can limit the values to a specific constructor by using the type parameter as is done in `arguments :: [Expr Argument]` but you can also just accept any expression using the type `Expr t` as in `isArgument`.

If you really really need run-time polymorphism, it can be achieved using the [`Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Typeable.html#t:Typeable) type-class which enables you to get runtime type information and do type-casts on opaque, generic types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Typeable

data Argument = Argument { ttype :: Type, value :: String } deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)
data Predicate = Predicate { lemma :: String, arguments :: [Argument] } deriving (Show, Eq, Typeable)

isArgument :: Typeable a => a -> Bool
isArgument a = case cast a of
    Just (Argument {}) -> True
    _                  -> False
```

The function [`cast`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) tries to convert any `Typeable a => a` value into some known type and returns a `Just` value if the type-cast succeeds and `Nothing` if it fails.

Comment: I was hoping to use a class to do this but the implementation instructions specifically ask for a function and not a class.

Comment: Ok, then you are probably expected to use the sum-type approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want by making Argument and Predicate part of the same type....

```
data LogicElement = Argument { ttype :: Type, value :: String } |
            Predicate { lemma :: String, arguments :: [LogicElement] } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

While it is possible to define a function of type (a->Bool), it is unusual, and generally implies that the value being input will be ignored (ie- how can you do anything to something if you don't even know what it is?  You pretty much can only apply other (a->b) functions on it).

In the particular example, you compiler will complain at the following

```
isArgument (Argument _) = True
```

because the pattern implicitly implies that the input argument must be type `Argument`, whereas the signature you gave was undefined type `a`.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for some reason because one of the fields is Argument.  If I remove "arguments :: [Argument]" it compiles, but I need that field.

Comment: My bad, I left the type of `argument` as `Argument`, when it too should have been changed to the new type name, `LogicElement`.  I've made the change, and it should compile now, although note that you might not like that predicates can be nested as arguments....  To tackle this better, I would need to know why you need the isArgument function to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that `isArgument` has type `a -> Bool`, you're saying that it can take *any*, or rather *every possible* `a`, not just certain ones.  There are a few solutions to this, though.  My preference would be that for simple alternatives, just use `Either`:

```
import Data.Either

isArgument :: Either Argument Predicate -> Bool
isArgument = isLeft
```

Or

```
-- Note the use of {} instead of _, the {} expands to all fields in a record
-- the _ only would have taken the place of the ttype field, although you could have
-- (Argument _ _) to capture both fields of the Argument constructor
isArgument :: Either Argument Predicate -> Bool
isArgument (Left (Argument {})) = True
isArgument _ = False
```

Although, the only use of this sort of function would be when you aren't sure which data type you have, and a value in Haskell can't be ambiguously typed.  It would be equivalent to if you had in Java/C/C++/C# something like

```cs
if (some_condition) {
    x = "a string";
} else {
    x = 5;
}
```

These are statically typed languages, a variable can't take on values of two different types.  The same holds in Haskell.  If you wanted to give a type to a variable that could take on two different values, you'd have to write a container for it.  The `Either` container in Haskell is pre-defined for this purpose.

Comment: I tried both of the solutions offered but they both failed when passed on an instance, e.g. "isArgument john" causes the interpreter to complain, even though "john" is an instance of data type "Argument"

Comment: @user3898238 You have to wrap each value of type `Argument` in the `Left` constructor and each value of type `Predicate` in the `Right` constructor.  This conversion does not happen automatically.  For example: `filter isArgument [Left (Argument x "an arg"), Right (Predicate "lemma" []), Left (Argument y "another arg")]` would return `[Left (Argument x "an arg"), Left (Argument y "another arg")]`.  This is starting to sound like an instance of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  Maybe it would help if you posted what you're trying to do, not what you'd like to do.